# Opengl View drawing issue

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

For dimension consideration, I resize the opengl view to 2.0 scale than origin, like this:

```
NSInteger Dimension = 2;
self.glView = [[WQPaintGLView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, width*Dimension, height*Dimension)];

CGAffineTransform tScale        = CGAffineTransformMakeScale((float)1/Dimension, (float)1/Dimension);
CGAffineTransform tTranslate    = CGAffineTransformTranslate(tScale, -width, -height);

self.glView.transform = tTranslate;

[self.canvasContainerView addSubview:self.glView];
```

But get a strange issue, see:

[image]

I can only draw stuff in the left bottom 1/4 area.

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `UIView` transform and openGL are not very compatible. Also the view resizing after the openGL initialization could be troublesome and in most cases a new render buffer must be created from the view.

Anyway since you scaled the view to have a larger surface you should check for following calls:

- `glViewport` should define what part of the buffer you are writing at. Usually it is set like (0, 0, viewWidth, viewHeight). In your case it must include the scale as well.
- `glOrtho` (or `glFrustum`) define your coordinate system if used. Those should most likely be the same no matter the view scale.
- Any other matrix usage or scissors that may be defined by the view's frame.

By all means if possible remove the transform on the view and try to find a better solution.